# how to get other user's id/name when he has the same record as logged in user in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have 2 tables, `users` and `profiles`,
and profiles has a field named graduated.

I want to show other users.name who's profile, graduated record as same as logged in user's profile.graduated

I'm new and the only think i know about calling logged in user is `$this->Auth->user('id');`

when we want to automatically put user's id in the form of adding a new record in a table related to user

Answer (score 0):

Make association with `Users` and `Profiles` and then use this:

```
$users_list = $this->Users->find()
                            ->where(['Profiles.graduated' => $this->Auth->user('graduated')])
                            ->contain(['Profiles'])
                            ->all();
```

You'll get all users in `$users_list`

Answer (score 0):

if you have `Users belongsTo Profiles` relationship

```
$query=$this->Users->find()->innerJoinWith('Profiles', function ($q) {
    return $q->where(['Profiles.graduated' => $this->Auth->user('graduated')]);
});

$query->toArray();
```